# Function that takes in string and return all vowels in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, return

From the below code after submitting it as a coding test challenge. I used to get the following feedback from a robot or a bot that is marking the challenge that task should RETURN an array of all the vowels found. The array must be in alphabetical order and lowercase but if I do run it on VS code it will print ['a', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'o'] And I don't know why. Please Clarify.

```
def task(string, vowels= "AaEeoiOoUu"):

    final = (each for each in a string if each in vowels)
   

    return (sorted(final))


string = "Two Owls and a Hen"
string = string.casefold()
print(task(string, vowels= "AaEeoiOoUu"))
```

Comment: your script will go letter by letter in whatever string is given and check if each character is a vowel or not. There's no logic for uniqueness, so if i gave it the string "aaaaa", it would return a list of 5 a's. If you want the list returns to be unique, use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), since sets enforce uniqueness by default

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over all the letters, loop over the vowels.

```
def task(string, vowels= "AaEeIiOoUu"):
    final = [vowel for vowel in vowels if vowel in string]
    return final
```

There's no need to call `sorted()` because the vowels are already sorted.

You also had a typo in `vowels`, an extra `o` instead of `I`

Comment: Should it be return - ```list(final)```   Otherwise, it will be just a *generator expression*.      Or List Comp... is fine

Comment: I changed it to a list comprehension